# Using iAds to purchase new apps?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, iad

I am making an iAd for my app, and I want to know if it is possible to allow users to purchase the full version of it using my iAd. Basically, these are the steps the user will need to take:

- Click the iAd
- Click the purchase button
- Enter Apple ID information
- Wait for the app to download

I know I have seen something like this before, but I cannot figure out how to get it to work. If it helps, I am using the iAd Producer application that Apple talks about. So, any ideas?

Comment: I believe you'd have to link them to the App Store page for your app. I don't think they can do an in-ad purchase.

Answer (score 0):

iAd Producer is targeted for advertising agencies so that their customers advertise on the iOS platform. Or we can advertise our new app through the network.

For us developers its pretty easy to use the iAd feed. You can check the details here on [iAd Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/iAd_Guide/Introduction/Introduction.html).

But I believe what you are looking for is In App Purchase. You can get everything here on its [guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html).

Good Luck.